# adding different version of GSON than default to retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, android-6.0-marshmallow

Regarding to this bug https://github.com/google/gson/issues/648
I would like to use newer version of GSON, however I can't use newer version of retrofit because till next release I don't have enough time to update API in all places, how can I use newest version of GSON in retrofit without updating retrofit then?

Answer (score 2):

First of all we need to exclude default dependency of gson from retrofit:

```
compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
}
```

Then just add dependency of newer version of gson:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```